# Replacing multiple occurrences of a character or string inside parentheses in R

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to replace commas within all sets of parentheses with a semicolon, but not change any commas outside of the parentheses.

So, for example:

```
"a, b, c (1, 2, 3), d, e (4, 5)"
```

should become:

```
"a, b, c (1; 2; 3), d, e (4; 5)"
```

I have started attempting this with gsub, but I am having a really hard time understanding/figuring out what how to identify those commas within the parentheses.

I would call myself an advanced beginner with R, but with regular expressions and text manipulations, a total noob. Any help you can provide would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The simplest solution**

A most common workaround that will work in case all parentheses are balanced:

```
,(?=[^()]*\))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/c6hec8/1). R code:

```
a <- "a, b, c (1, 2, 3), d, e (4, 5)"
gsub(",(?=[^()]*\\))", ";", a, perl=T)
## [1] "a, b, c (1; 2; 3), d, e (4; 5)"
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/swPtEc)

The regex matches...

- `,` - a comma if...
- `(?=[^()]*\))` - it is followed by 0 or more characters other than `(` or `)` (with `[^()]*`) and a literal `)`.

**Alternative solutions**

If you need to make sure only commas inside the closest open and close parentheses are replaced, it is safer to use a `gsubfn` based approach:

```
library(gsubfn)
x <- 'a, b, c (1, 2, 3), d, e (4, 5)'
gsubfn('\\(([^()]*)\\)', function(match) gsub(',', ';', match, fixed=TRUE), x, backref=0)
## => [1] "a, b, c (1; 2; 3), d, e (4; 5)"
```

Here, `\(([^()]*)\)` matches `(`, then 0+ chars other than `(` and `)` and then `)`, and after that the `match` found is passed to the anonymous function where all `,` chars are replaced with semi-colons using `gsub`.

If you need to perform this replacement inside balanced parentheses with unknown level depth use a PCRE regex with `gsubfn`:

```
x1 <- 'a, b, c (1, (2, (3, 4)), 5), d, e (4, 5)'
gsubfn('\\(((?:[^()]++|(?R))*)\\)', function(match) gsub(',', ';', match, fixed=TRUE), x1, backref=0, perl=TRUE)
## => [1] "a, b, c (1; (2; (3; 4)); 5), d, e (4; 5)"
```

**Pattern details**

```
\(             # Open parenthesis
  (            # Start group 1
   (?:         # Start of a non-capturing group:
     [^()]++   # Any 1 or more chars other than '(' and ')'
     |         #   OR
      (?R)     # Recursively match the entire pattern
   )*          # End of the non-capturing group and repeat it zero or more times
  )            # End of Group 1 (its value will be passed to the `gsub` via `match`)
\)             # A literal ')'
```

Comment: +1 for teaching me something new about `regex`, in this case the positive lookahead. BTW: http://www.regexr.com/# nice resource to learn `regex`

Comment: @thothal: I'd prefer [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) to test PCRE/Perl-like regular expressions. The look-ahead is working due to `perl=T` here.

Answer (score 0):

```
gsub("(?<=\\d),", ";", string, perl=T)
```

Comment: I also noticed such a pattern, but the OP's description is `I am trying to replace commas within all sets of parentheses with a semicolon,` and it is also in the title (it is hard to miss)

Comment: I tested again, it is replace commas in parentheses with a semicolon.

Comment: It will replace that.  But, the condition I am talking about is inside the parentheses.  Your lookaround is testing for `digit` followed by a comma.